# How to use datePicker when selected with an button to display text in a text view

Tags: ipad, date, picker

Iam trying to have text displayed in a txt view when the date is picked by a button in a date picker....so when the date picker is on jan 30,2010 (or what every date you want) you press the select button and the sentence for that day (or what ever day you pick) pops up in the txt view..... each sentence is different for each day
Doing the code in Xcode for iPad
Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

get the date from date picker on a button event in a string as -

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSString *dateStr = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[datePickerView date]] retain];
```

then set this string to a label as -

```
[label setText:dateStr];
```